# jqplot y-axis text height had clip

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

In y-axis i used text for 2 line with "/n" but my text has been clipping 
how to expand text line height ?

```
 axesDefaults: {
            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
            tickOptions: {
                angle: 0,
                fontSize: '10pt'
            },
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
            labelOptions: {
                //angle: -90,
                fontSize: '10pt'
            }
        },
        axes: {
            yaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                label: ' ',
                //Group Category Name
                ticks: groupname,
                tickOptions: { fontSize: '11px', labelPosition:'middle', formatString :'%d'}
            },
            xaxis:
            {
                tickOptions: { angle: 0, fontSize: '11px', formatString :'%d' },
                max: MaxX
            }
        }
```

Thank you

http://img252.imageshack.us/img252/6821/20130122221030.png

Comment: You can try to specify value for `tickSpacing` option of your yaxis.See  http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.tickSpacing

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tickSpacing` in y axis

```
tickSpacing = 75
```

Approximate pixel spacing between ticks on graph.  Used during autoscaling.  This number will be an upper bound, actual spacing will be less.

Reference:
http://insar.miami.edu/timeseries/dist/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html